# AdminJS Filter resources with mongodb object ID

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, adminjs

is there a way to show only resources from a given user?

Ive a User Schema and a Items Schema with Ref on User. I only want to show items from the currentAdmin.

Here is my current code:

```js
const customBefore = (request: { query: any }, context: any) => {
  const {query = {}} = request
  const newQuery = {
    ...query,
    ['filters.user']: context.currentAdmin._id
  }

  request.query = newQuery

  return request
}
```

Im getting `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'type')` error